# using WITH clause in @Query JPA Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to use this query from here - http://technoir.blog/blog/post/timeseries_tips_for_postgresql:

```
with filled_dates as (
  select day, 0 as blank_count from
    generate_series('2014-01-01 00:00'::timestamptz, current_date::timestamptz, '1 day') 
      as day
),
signup_counts as (
  select date_trunc('day', created_at) as day, count(*) as signups
    from users
  group by date_trunc('day', created_at)
)
select filled_dates.day, 
       coalesce(signup_counts.signups, filled_dates.blank_count) as signups
  from filled_dates
    left outer join signup_counts on signup_counts.day = filled_dates.day
  order by filled_dates.day
```

When I put this in `@Query("WITH filled_dates as ( .... ")`, it throws this error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: WITH near line 1, column 1 [WITH filled_dates as
```

How can I use WITH clause in manual JPA queries?

Comment: you would consult documentation about what is JPQL and realise that SQL != JPQL, and Spring has some "nativeQuery" flag. But then you've already been through docs, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `nativeQuery=true` in the annotation to switch to plain SQL. Otherwise it expects JPQL queries.

`@Query(value = "WITH filled_dates AS ...", nativeQuery=true)`

Also, make sure you've formatted it correctly for Java in terms of spaces, quotes etc.

If you want to use parameters, use positional instead of named parameters.

For example (a bit silly):

```
@Query(value="select * from emp where name=?1 and dept=?2", nativeQuery=true)
public Collection<Employee> findEmployeesByNameAndDept(String name, String dept);
```

Adding such a complex query to Java code using JPA seems like a poor idea though. Maybe you should use a stored procedure or function or somesuch.

Comment: I am yet to understand how to use a stored procedure for this kind of queries. Can you help me give a starting point?

Comment: @nirvair Sorry, but I'm not an expert in that area either. What I'd suggest is to open a new question with that as the focus. SO might not be the best place for that though. Post your current code (with the huge query in Java) at codereview.stackexchange.com and ask how it can be made better. Meanwhile, if adding nativeQuery at least resolved the error, you could accept this answer so it may help others!

Comment: one more query. How can I add parameters in this query? Would it be the same way as it was in JPQL?

Comment: @nirvair Use positional parameters like `?1`, `?2` etc and maintain the same order in arguments.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @nirvair Edited my answer, please check now.